# Find probability of intersection given sum of probabilities of pairwise intersections

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question is as follows:
If $A_{1}, A_{2}, ..., A_{n}$ are events such that  $$\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} P(A_{i}A_{j}) > {{n}\choose{2}} - 1,$$ 
prove or disprove $$P(A_{1}A_{2}...A_{n})>0.$$
My intuition tells me that it's true, but I'm not at all sure how to prove it.

Comment: What is $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}^{\infty}$?

Comment: It's a typo :) the infinity shouldn't be there. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(1-\mathbb{P}\{A_i^c\cup A_j^c\})>\binom{n}{2}-1 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \mathbb{P}\{A_i^c\cup A_j^c\}<1.
$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{\bigcap_{i}A_i\right\}=1-\mathbb{P}\left\{\bigcup_{i}A_i^c\right\}\ge 1-\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}P\{A_i^c\cup A_j^c\}>0.
$$

Comment: Great and simple solution! I can't believe I didn't think of it. If only I could give you 2 upvotes... Thank you!

Comment: Actually, now that I've started analyzing the solution a but further, there's one thing that's unclear to me: in the next-to-last step, you use $P({\cup}_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}^{c}) \leq \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} P(A_{i}^{c} \cup A_{j}^{c})$. Could you explain why that holds?

Comment: Never mind the last question, I was able to clear it up: if we write each component of the union several times, we can separate them two by two and thus obtain the inequality.